# Java - copy JPG while preserving all file attributes

Tags: java, copy, jpeg

What is the best way to move/copy file while maintaining all its attributes (Date created, Date, etc)?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using Java 7, use `java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`

Use the COPY_ATTRIBUTES option to maintain the last modified time:

> COPY_ATTRIBUTES
>   Attempts to copy the file attributes associated with this file to the
>   target file. The exact file attributes that are copied is platform and
>   file system dependent and therefore unspecified. *Minimally, the
>   last-modified-time is copied to the target file if supported by both
>   the source and target file store*. Copying of file timestamps may
>   result in precision loss.

Emphasis added

For Java 6 and earlier, Apache commons has a function to copy files

```
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile,
boolean preserveFileDate)
```

Note the comments

> Setting preserveFileDate to true tries to preserve the file's last
>   modified date/times using File.setLastModified(long), however it is
>   not guaranteed that the operation will succeed. If the modification
>   operation fails, no indication is provided.

This will only try to preserve the modified date, and not other file attributes.

Otherwise, you will have to use Runtime.exec or something similar to run an external process.

Comment: except for the lastModified date

Comment: I am using Java 6, I was thinking of running external batch for the move/copy example:
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "move.bat"});