# Stop Gradle from modifying my image/file attribute info on copy

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have an application that sorts images based on attribute data such as date last modified. In my unit tests resource folder I have images test/resources/folder that get copied to a build/resources/test automatically when calling "gradle build".

The problem is I need the files to have the same last modified date for testing.

Is it possible to use javas Files.copy in my build script to move the data and maintain it's attributes? Or is there a way to tell gradle to stop messing with my files?

Gradle task:

```
task copyImages(type :Copy){
    from 'src/test/resources'
    into 'build/resources/test'
}
```

**Update:**

My solution based on feedback was to use JavaExec

**Gradle Build Script:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

task(moveImages, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec){
    main = 'com.lifehug.support.TestSupport'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    args 'src/test/resources/navigator', 'build/resources/test/navigator'
}

defaultTasks 'moveImages'
```

And then here is my java file to move the images

**Java File:**

```
public class TestSupport{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

            if( args.length < 2) return;

            final Path sourceDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
            final Path targetDir = Paths.get(args[1]);

            Files.walkFileTree(sourceDir, EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS), Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,  BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException  {
                    Path target = targetDir.resolve(sourceDir.relativize(dir));
                    Files.copy(dir, target, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    Files.copy(file, targetDir.resolve(sourceDir.relativize(file)), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
             }

           });

    }

}
```

Comment: I suppose a workaround would be to use ant.copy(preservelastmodified: true, ...) -- but it would be nice to know how to do this with native Gradle.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I'm going to try the java route, but I agree this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking at [Gradle Copy task](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) documentation I could not find a way for preserving the file timestamp. Doing some more research apparently there's an [open issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2698) on that.

As a workaround you can use alternative ways to copy, e.g. using ant.copy as [@dnault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611819/dnault) suggested or just use java code (see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643511/java-copy-jpg-while-preserving-all-file-attributes) for Java 6 and Java 7).

Comment: Noob question I assume, but can I use java code in my build.gradle script? Or do you mean create a java program and have Gradle run it?

Comment: Gradle is built over Groovy which is built over Java. In other words, you can use Java freely in your gradle scripts.